# Why I am facing this error while using Serenium module of python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")[0].click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ig_bot = InstagramBot('temp_username', 'temp_password')
```

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaQzy.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages. Actually attach the error to the post.

Comment: Presumably you have that error because the page hasn't finished loading when you try to find the username field.